# Setting Constraint between two fields in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table, with two columns, Enter_Time and Leave_Time, how to write a CREATE TABLE script that enforces the constraint Leave_Time > Enter_Time?

Edit: Microsoft Access is used

Comment: You don't say what brand of RDBMS you are using.  Note that MySQL does not support CHECK constraints as described in most people's answers.

Answer (score 3):

Using [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  -- other columns...

  enter_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
  leave_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ck_interval CHECK (leave_time > enter_time)
);
```

Comment: What is the value of leave_time when the record is inserted?  EOT - end of time?

Comment: With the above declaration you have to provide values when inserting. Omitting them raises a null-constraint error. You can add `DEFAULT 'infinity'::timestamptz` to the declaration (or insert it explicitly every time) to achieve an end of time value.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    Leave_Time DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    Enter_Time DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT CHK_TIMES CHECK (Leave_Time > Enter_Time));
```

Comment: CHECK(Leave_Time IS NULL OR Leave_Time > Enter_Time).  Best to make Enter_Time at least a non-null column.

Comment: Very true, Jonathan.  Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your SQL database engine.  Assuming Microsoft SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Timecard](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EnterTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [LeaveTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Timecard] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Timecard]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Timecard] CHECK  (([EnterTime]<[LeaveTime]))
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Timecard] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Timecard]
```

But your question was *how* to write it... I only just wrote it for you.  The *how* I did it is more generally useful:  I used Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express (free program) and created a table and constraint using the GUI.  Then I asked it for the CREATE script.  That way I didn't have to be a SQL wizard to write up the above code.